# No Simcard installed - iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, sim

I've got an iPhone 5 running the latest iOS 7 version. (I don't feel like testing the first pre-released iOS 8).
The iPhone randomly displays me **"No sim card installed"** in a pop-up and I have no provider in the left-top of the menu.

What have I tried:

- [Toggling AirPlane mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4148?utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitterfeed) <sub>(this does not work)</sub>
- Hard reset <sub>(this works)</sub>
- Removing the sim card using a paperclip and placing it back <sub>(this also works)</sub>

What I didn't try:

- Restoring the device <sub>I don't see why restoring my iPhone would solve this problem.</sub>

  What can cause this issue? 
  <sub>I'm still under warranty by the European law (which is 24 months for an iPhone)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a new iPhone. Apple analyzed the iPhone and replaced it.

Answer (score 2):

This is often caused (but by no means is this the only possible cause) by a badly fitting sim card, or sim tray.  That doesn't explain how a hard reset would make it work though.  I would see if you can borrow a friendly sim and tray from another iPhone 5 users, and see if you can get the same results, or improved results, by using different combinations of sim card and tray.  When you get one that works, run away and leave your friend with the duff bits ;)

Comment: How can that be the case after using the same sim, tray and iPhone for over 20 months straight?

Comment: Vote up for the last lines, you're a sneaky bastard

Comment: :)  But seriously, it's a moving part that is only held in place by friction and a tiny sprung plate.  A couple of drops could, in theory, loosen it up a little.  Also, is your Nano Sim cut down, or factory nano?  I had a Micro Sim on my iPhone 4 which only worked if I trimmed a mm off one side then taped it to the underside of the tray...

Comment: It's a factory nano.

Answer (score 1):

The most certain way to get the problem solved correctly is to take your iPhone to your mobile phone service provider and get them to troubleshoot the problem, perhaps giving you a new SIM card. If they cannot solve the problem, then you should take the iPhone to an Apple Store or other Apple-certified service provider and let them work on it.

Having reliable phone service is important; you should let the professionals deal with this annoying issue to ensure that you have continous phone service.

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself: you still have warranty. If the problem keeps occurring I would use that warranty while it still lasts.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clever workaround  . just ask Siri  to turn cellular data off